# Subidas de archivos según extensión en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un problema... tengo dos archivos, uno en php, que se denomina **subidas.php**:

```html
<html>
<center>
Por Favor Solo archivos de extenciones: Patch, INI o Gif
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
 <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><p>
 <input type="submit" value="Subir archivo" />
 </form>
</center>
<p>
</html>
```

el segundo archivo es **uploader.php**, cuyo código fuente es:

```
    <?php
if ($_FILES['archivo']["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES['archivo']['error'] . "<br>";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Nombre: " . $_FILES['archivo']['name'] . "<br>";
  echo "Tipo: " . $_FILES['archivo']['type'] . "<br>";
  echo "Tamaño: " . ($_FILES["archivo"]["size"] / 100000000) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Carpeta temporal: " . $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'] . " <p>";

$target_path  =  "uploads/";
$target_path  =  $target_path  .  basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
  echo "Nombre: " . $_FILES['archivo']['name'] . "<br>";
  echo "Tipo: " . $_FILES['archivo']['type'] . "<br>";
  echo "Tamaño: " . ($_FILES["archivo"]["size"] / 100000000) . " kB<br>";
  echo "Carpeta temporal: " . $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'] . " <br>";
    echo "El archivo " . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']) . " se ha subido con éxito";
} else {
    echo "Hubo un error subiendo el archivo, por favor inténtalo de nuevo!";
}}
?>
```

Quiero que suba sólo archivos .ini y .patch pero no sé por qué no me realiza la subida.
¿Alguien me ayuda a detectar mi error? Por favor, añadiendo **(echo)** según la impresión no sale ni siquiera el tipo de archivo subido ni el tipo de extensión.
Para facilitar copiar y pegar los códigos, dejo abajo el resultado de un archivo de extensión **.ini**. Después de su subida el sube el archivo pero NO compara, o sea, no entiendo por qué se cuela el archivo **si ext es = a NULL**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: has **var_dump($_FILES['uploadedfile']['error']);** y ve si no me manda algun código

Answer (score 1):

Deberías cambiar la referencia al archivo, es decir:

donde aparece: `$_FILES['archivo']`

debería aparecer: `$_FILES['uploadedfile']`

El índice del array $_FILES está dado por la propiedad "name" del tag input, que en este caso es "uploadedfile".

Answer (score 0):

Comprueba el tipo de archivo que se está subiendo de esta manera:

```
$permitidos =  array('ini','patch');
$filename = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(!in_array($ext,$permitidos) ) {
    echo 'El archivo no tiene la extensión .ini o .patch';
}
```

Comment: me sale como NULL de hecho modificare el uploader.php y veras el resultado no se por que no detecta la extención

Comment: me dice que el archivo no es .ini pero si lo es es un archivo.ini